# Is aliasing over a coreutil command a bad idea?

Tags: shell, alias

I frequently find myself copying large directories and then thinking "darn, I should've used rsync instead of cp for this because I can get progress updates".

I'm considering adding this to my `.profile`:

```
alias cp='rsync -a --progress'
```

1. In general, could aliasing over another command cause any problems? What about coreutil commands specifically?
2. Are there any foreseeable problems that would arise from this particular alias?

Comment: my initial thought was that some shell scripts might assume *any* output from cp indicates a failure... but this alias wouldn't extend to shell scripts, would it?

Comment: This sort of thing is pretty common. Distros will often alias certain commands to automatically use certain options (for example on my system `ls --color=auto` is aliased to just `ls`. If you want to do this, you're free to do so, just realize what effect it's going to have on commands that you copy/paste and that `cp` is now no longer actually `cp`

Comment: It is subjective whether this is a bad idea, but I'd suggest most people would tell you it is, mostly because it is changing the behaviour of `cp`, as by default `cp` is not recursive, yet that `rsync` command is.

Comment: Not answering the question, but if you often have this problem, just kill cp (^C) and run the rsync command. It won't copy anything already copied so there is no harm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems include motor memory if then on somebody else's system where that alias is not setup and then something bad happens as you were expecting `rsync` but `cp` happened instead (trailing slashes or lack thereof may be different between the two commands). Or you could get in the habit of passing `rsync` flags to something called `cp`, something again bad to memorize if `cp` ever is not-`rsync` and then who knows what happens when `cp` gets `rsync` flags? Probably easier to create a not-cp-nor-rsync alias and train yourself to use that instead, or to think about the command for a few seconds before hitting enter.